# Orion contextBroker allows set read preference to Mongodb replicaset?

Tags: fiware-orion

I'm reading the documentation of orion Context Broker and in the command line arguments I dont see any argument to set the read preference to my replicaset of mongoDB. In my application I need to set that the read preference have the option nearest to avoid bottle necks in high query traffic periods. Does anyone know if is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Current Orion version (3.3.1) doesn't allow to set read preference. There is [an open issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3794) in the Orion repository about implement the `-mongoUri` CLI parameter to allow setting the MongoDB connection URI (so you could add for instance `&readPreference=secondary` to it).

Alternatively, you could hack the Orion source code to build an specific version for you with the `readPreference` value you want. Have a look to [`composeMongoUri()` function](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/src/lib/mongoDriver/mongoConnectionPool.cpp#L317). It seems it is a matter of just addding `uri += optionPrefix + "readPreference=<whatever you want>";` at the end.

It is not a smart soluction (it is not flexible and you would need to rebuild Orion if you want to change the setting) but it could be a valid workaround while `-mongoUri` gets implemented.

**EDIT:** `-dbURI` (the final name changed from `-mongoUri`) has been finally implemented. It is currently available in the `telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:latest` dockerhub build and it will be available in Orion 3.11.0 (to be released soon).

Comment: Thanks a lot @fgalan. I'll check this solution and make the workaround meanwhile the issue is solved. Thanks again

Comment: Some new information was added to answer post (see EDIT section)