# FIWARE orion with atlas mongodb

Tags: mongodb-atlas, fiware-orion

Hello I'm trying to launch the FIWARE orion context broker using an atlas mongodb

```
mongodb+srv://<user>:****************@<domainid>.mongodb.net/<aut_db>
```

I have tried multiple variations of the docker run command but I never get the connection to success

**trace:**

```
$ docker run --name orion -p 1027:1026 fiware/orion:latest -dbhost "<domainid>.mongodb.net/<aut_db>?ssl=true&retryWrites=true&w=majority" -dbuser <user> -dbpwd U9NjLafksdv9mavW -logLevel DEBUG

time=2021-12-01T14:38:42.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[1063]:main | msg=start command line </usr/bin/contextBroker -fg -multiservice -ngsiv1Autocast -disableFileLog -dbhost <domainid>.mongodb.net/<aut_db>?ssl=true&retryWrites=true&w=majority -dbuser <user> -dbpwd ****** -logLevel DEBUG>
time=2021-12-01T14:38:42.188Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[1137]:main | msg=Orion Context Broker is running
time=2021-12-01T14:40:23.011Z | lvl=ERROR | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=mongoConnectionPool.cpp[220]:mongoConnect | msg=Database Startup Error (cannot connect to mongo - doing 100 retries with a 1000 millisecond interval)
time=2021-12-01T14:40:23.011Z | lvl=FATAL | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=MongoGlobal.cpp[142]:mongoInit | msg=Fatal Error (MongoDB error)
time=2021-12-01T14:40:23.012Z | lvl=INFO | corr=N/A | trans=N/A | from=N/A | srv=N/A | subsrv=N/A | comp=Orion | op=contextBroker.cpp[591]:exitFunc | msg=Orion shutdown completed
```

Has someone know how I can configure orion context broker to connect to an mongo atlas?

EDIT: I have checked and I have access from that server to the mongo-db with the mongo shell

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Orion currently supports only `mongodb://` connection strings, built from the `-db`, `-dbhost`, `-rplSet`, `-dbTimeout`, `-dbuser`, `-dbpwd`, `-dbAuthMech`, `-dbAuthDb`, `-dbSSL` and `-dbDisableRetryWrites` [CLI parameters](https://fiware-orion.readthedocs.io/en/master/admin/cli/index.html)(or default values, if omitted) as can be see [in the source code](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/3.4.0/src/lib/mongoDriver/mongoConnectionPool.cpp#L332-L384).

There is [an issue in the Orion repository](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/issues/3794) with the aim of making this more flexible, allowing to provide the connection string directly overriding the above parameters.

While that issue comes (contributions welcome ;) you could hack the Orion source code cited above to build an specific version for you with support for `mongo+srv://` connection strings.

**EDIT:** `-dbURI` has been finally implemented. It is currently available in the `telefonicaiot/fiware-orion:latest` dockerhub build and it will be available in Orion 3.11.0 (to be released soon).

Comment: Similar answer to this one provided in another question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/69944749/1485926

Comment: Just an info regarding Orion-LD: Currently `-dbSSL` is not supported by Orion-LD version 1.01 [, but will be available in future](https://github.com/FIWARE/context.Orion-LD/issues/903)

Comment: Some new information was added to answer post (see EDIT section)